# Как грамотно писать программы на JavaFX?

Tags: java, javafx

Все началось со Swing. Там вроде все понятно: создаешь классы, делаешь их взаимодействие, вешаешь слушателей на кнопки... Потом я решил быстро переписать программу на JavaFX.

Первом делом прочел 3 главы о JavaFX в книге Шилда "Java 8. Полной руководство". После этого начал читать "introducing javafx 8 programming" того же автора. Показалось, что управлять JavaFX примерно так же, как и Swing. НО... В процессе разработки возникает огромное множество вопросов, которых не было в Swing.

Например, почему в IntelliJ Idea есть пункт создания JavaFX-проекта, если можно любой класс унаследовать от Application ? Как создавать приложения с использованием FXML ? Как связан fxml-файл с моими классами ? Чем собираются JavaFX - приложения ? Стоит ли использовать SceneBuilder ? Как пользоваться MVC моделью ? Что вообще происходит ?

В общем, не смотря на поэму выше, вопрос простой - как правильно начать JavaFX проект и как его строить в дальнейшем, чтобы было минимум проблем ? Есть ли какие-нибудь источники, которые смогут ответить на мои вопросы ?

Comment: как старт прочтите вот этот [туториал](http://code.makery.ch/library/javafx-8-tutorial/ru/part1/) он не ответит на все вопросы зато упорядочит оставшиеся...

Comment: Если только начинаешь то не берись сразу за FXML, сначала без него потренируйся, а по JavaFX лучше почитай "Learn JavaFX 8" автор - Kishori Sharan, там все подробнее и более доходчиво расписано.

Comment: Отличный комментарий, обязательно посмотрю книгу.

Comment: Я лично рассматриваю JavaFX проект, как простой проект на Java. Т.е. я создаю иерархию модулей и собираю это с помощью gradle. Использую IntelliJ Idea как средство работы с Java кодом. Idea даже не знает, что я именно GUI приложение делаю. Т.е. я не использую SceneBuilder. Так же я полностью отказался от FXML. С другой стороны получается достаточно гибко и легко расширяется. Вот [пример](https://github.com/StanleyProjects/Cudgel/tree/dev). Достаточно интересная тема, так что если задашь более конкретные вопросы то получится получить полезный опыт.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ну чтож. Я тебе мозги запудрил, я тебе и объясню.

1. В идее как и во всех нормальных IDE есть заготовки приложений. Да ты можешь наследовать любой класс от Application. Если в заготовке идеи это сделано с основным класом, это еще не запрещает тебе делать по другому.
2. Что из себя представляет приложение с FXML. Его можно сравнить с вебсайтом:

   1. **FXML** это файл разметки. Там описаны элементы интерфейса: их имена, расположение, первичные настройки, а также имена методов, которые будут вызываться при том или ином действии.
   2. Также он привязывается к **контроллеру**. Это такое связуещее звено между логикой твоего приложения и интерфейсом. Там объявлены объекты элементов интерфейса, с которыми тебе нужно взаимодействовать, а также методы, срабатывающие при работе с твоим интерфейсом (этакие eventHandlerы для кнопок и прочего). При этом тебе не нужно самому инициализировать и настраивать элементы интерфейса в нем. Экземпляр этого класса со всеми привязками и активным наполнением создается при загрузке fxml.
3. Приложения JavaFX собираются так же как и обычные. Внешних костылей не используется, все написано на родном коде и встроено в JDK (начиная с 8)
4. SceneBuilder - визуальный редактор верстки интерфейса. Там ты наглядно видишь, что из себя будет представлять интерфейс приложения. И не надо будет по сотню раз перезапускать приложение, сверяясь, правильно ли ты отверстал таблицу.